# ExactTarget - Insert Row in Data Extension using REST API - CustomObjectNotFound

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions, error-messages

I'm trying to add rows into a data extension in exact target but I'm getting this error:

> Failed to resolve the Custom Object from the provided ObjectReferenceIdentifier`.

For testing purposes, my data extension is limited to the strict minimum : 
1 field called `Email` of type `EmailAddress` which is also my Primary Key.

I'm trying to insert data using the REST API as following

```
curl -X POST \
  https://www.exacttargetapis.com/data/v1/async/dataextensions/key:my_external_key/rows \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer my_access_token' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "items":[{
        "Email":"myname@company.com"
    }]
}'
```

And I'm receiving the following error:

```
{
    "requestId": "1b6f96ce-66e2-451a-9a21-f53f8d8f6b3d",
    "resultMessages": [
        {
            "resultType": "Operational",
            "resultClass": "Error",
            "resultCode": "CustomObjectNotFound",
            "message": "Failed to resolve the Custom Object from the provided ObjectReferenceIdentifier [Id: Null, Key: mics_test]."
        }
    ]
}
```

And I've not been able to identify the origin of this error.

Comment: From a glance, it seems that your external key for the DE is not available in the BU you are trying to insert into. I would verify the ClientId/Secret you are using are for the correct BU that contains the DE.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed a question of rights the async API need to be activated by a SFMC account manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easier reference to anyone else that has this issue:

From a glance, it seems that your external key for the DE is not available in the BU you are trying to insert into. I would verify the ClientId/Secret you are using are for the correct BU that contains the DE.

OP response - Thanks, it was indeed a question of rights the async API need to be activated by a SFMC account manager.